# Parse float, decimal or double

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point

I'm in the process of rewriting our flat file parser, from a ungeneric, attribute oriented thingy to a more modern fluent synstax thingy. I have a problem coming up with a good way to deal with floating point numbers

Given this DTO

```
public class Foo 
{
   public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

And this flatfile

```
1234561234
```

You configure mapping like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo>()
.Map(f => f.DecimalValue)
.Decimal(10, 4); //Length 10, precision 4
```

Deserialize

```
var result = Mapper<Foo>.Read(flatfile);
```

It will result in a foo object with a property with value 123456.1234

I have working code for this, but its hardcoded for decimal values only. 
I'm trying to find a good generic way for this. One problem is that there is no generic constaint for floating numbers.

The generic `Map` method from above example

```
    public PropertyMapResult<TType, TProperty> Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TType, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var result = new PropertyMapResult<TType, TProperty>(this, expression);
        propertyMappers.Add(result);
        return result;
    }
```

The problem method, `Decimal`, looks like this

```
    public MapResult<TType> Decimal(int length, int precision)
    {
        this.length = length;
        toFormater = s => (TProperty)FormatDecimal(s, precision);
        fromFormater = property => string.Empty; //TODO: fix Writing of decimal, also fix support for double and float

        return parent;
    }
```

And its underlying `FormatDecimal`

```
    private object FormatDecimal(string data, int precision)
    {
        var integer = ConvertTo<decimal>(data);
        var frac = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);

        return integer/frac;
    }
```

One way is to overload all of above methids, one for each floating number type, not very optimal. I tried using dynamic casting i the `FormatDecimal` method but that does not help

Any ideas?

Comment: **attribute oriented thingy to a more modern fluent synstax thingy** lol!

Comment: Yeah well, attributes do pollute the DTO's with dependencies they should not have